# How can I test Vue 3 component with Pinia and axios token

Tags: axios, jestjs, token, vuejs3, pinia

I have a component which calls a store called users:

Store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useUserApiStore = defineStore('userApiStore', {
    state: () => ({
    }),
    actions: {
        list(filter) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_LIST;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(url, {
                    params: {
                        filter: filter,
                    },
                }).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        listPaginated(params) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_LIST_PAGINATE;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(url, {
                    params: params,
                }).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        get(id) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_SHOW;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(url.replace(":id", id)).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        delete(id) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_DELETE;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.delete(url, { params: { id: id } }).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        /* TABS */
        store(params) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_STORE;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post(url, params).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        update(params) {
            const url = import.meta.env.VITE_URL_GLOBALTANK_BASE_API + import.meta.env.VITE_EP_USERS_UPDATE;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.put(url, params).then(res => {
                    resolve(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

My component UsersView has the method onMounted that calls getData from store:

```
onMounted(() => {
     getData();
});

const getData = (numPage = 0) => {
     let params = {
          paginate: model.paginate,
          filter: model.filter,
          page: model.current_page,
     };

     if (numPage > 0) {
          params.page = numPage;
          model.current_page = numPage;
     }

     userApiStore
          .listPaginated(params)
          .then((res) => {
               model.data = res.data.data;
               console.log("data", model.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
               if (err.response.status === 401) console.log("UNAUTHORIZED");
               notificationsStore.showToast(t("notifications.unknown_error"), "error");
          });
};
```

And my UsersVew test:

```
it("should render users list", async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(UsersView, {
            global: {
                plugins: [createTestingPinia({ createSpy: vi.fn, stubActions: false })]
            }
        })

        await flushPromises()
        const usersList = wrapper.findAllComponents('[data-test="users-list"]')
        console.log(usersList)
    })
```

The problem is that I have a previous login where I get the access_token and I put it globally in axios headers like this:

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =` Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`;`

But I want to test my component but my component doesn't has the token globally when I throw the tests the list of users is empty

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful